# the url ends with a number cannot get 404 page?

Tags: wordpress

For example,

`www.myweb.com/page/subpage/subpagetwo/` is my url

if I add any numbers to the end like

`www.myweb.com/page/subpage/subpagetwo/`**23423423**
`www.myweb.com/page/subpage/subpagetwo/`**3453453113132**

I cannot get 404 error page, if replace those numbers to letters, works fine.
Could please someone give some advices? thanks

Comment: what *do* you get if not the 404 page?

Comment: I get the page before the number. if the url like this `www.myweb.com/page/subpage/subpagetwo/3453453113132`, then I page I see is `www.myweb.com/page/subpage/subpagetwo/`

Comment: What are you using for your permalinks settings? Anything extra in the `.htaccess` file in the root of your WordPress install?

Comment: have one line redirection `RewriteRule ^page/$ "page/subpage" [R=301,L]` in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: did you try commenting out that rule to see if it's the problem? fwiw I would probably use `RewriteRule ^page/?$ page/subpage/ [R=301,L]` - not sure if the double quotes hurt, but i do know you don't need them, and you can make the trailing forward slash optional.